# implicit differentiaition.

Tags: derivatives, optimization

Given : $Pf'(L)-w=0$, $Pf(L)=wL+c$, $f$ is twice diiferentiable, $f'(L)>0$, $f''(L)<0$, all variable are positive, $w$, $c$ are exogenous variable and $P$ & $L$ are endogenous variable.

To find : $\frac{\partial P}{\partial w}$ ,  $\frac{\partial P} {\partial c}$ ,  $\frac{\partial L}{\partial w}$ and  $\frac{\partial L}{\partial c}$

I equated the values of P from both the equations and got the resulting equation as
$wf'(L).L+cf'(L)-wf(L)=z$

I am able to solve for $\frac{\partial L}{\partial w}$ and  $\frac{\partial L}{\partial c}$, which are

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w}=\frac{f(L)-L.f'(L)}{wf''(L).L+cf''(L)}$ and  $\frac{\partial L}{\partial c}=\frac{f'(L)}{wf''(L).L+cf''(L)}$

But, I am not able to find $\frac{$\partial P}{$\partial w}$ and  $\frac{$\partial P}{$\partial c}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: Welcome ! Please tell what you have tried so far so that the community can help you better.